# How to remove a specific value from an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose, i have an **array**

```
const anArray = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4', 'value 5'];
```

If i want to remove the `value 3` from `anArray` but don't know the position of that value in the array, how can i remove that?

*Note: I'm a beginner in JavaScript*

Comment: [Array​.prototype​.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to get the index, and `splice` to delete:

```js
const anArray = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4', 'value 5'];
anArray.splice(anArray.indexOf("value 3"), 1);
console.log(anArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks...Btw, what's the last line for?

Comment: You mean the CSS @shiro13? It just expands the console to spare you from scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

filter will give you a new array with values except `value 3` this will remove all the `value 3` if you want only first `value 3` to be removed you can use splice as given in other answer

```js
const anArray = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4', 'value 5'];

const filtered = anArray.filter(val=> val !== 'value 3')

console.log(filtered)
```